# WebView onPageFinished finish after onCreate

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Currently I have a WebView onPageFinished that contain `JavaScript` code that retrieve value. For some reason, the `JavaScript` code always finish retrieving after onCreate finish. Thus making any code that is dependable on the supposedly retrieve value return null error. Making me unable to use the retrieve data. I'm beyond frustrated with this problem. I've been searching high and low for solution but to no avail.

Here is my class `WebViewActivity`

```
 public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{

String[] paraText;
WebView webview;
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
TextToSpeech textToSpeech;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_voice);
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    });


    //Retrieve value from CustomAdapter
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String address = intent.getStringExtra("URL");

        webViewLoadURL(address);



}

//An instance of this class will be registered as a JavaScript interface
@JavascriptInterface
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void onData(String[] value){
    this.paraText = value;
    Log.d("Output Test: Value :",value[0]);
    Log.d("Output Test: P.Text :",paraText[0]);

}

public void webViewLoadURL(String address){



    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(this,"myjava");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

            Log.d("Output Test:"," shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.d("Output Test:"," onPageStarted");

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:"
                    + "var paraTexts = [];"
                    + "var count = document.getElementsByTagName('p');"
                    + "var loop;"
                    + "for(loop = 0; loop < count.length; loop++){"
                    + "paraTexts.push(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[loop].innerHTML);"
                    +"}"
                    + "myjava.onData(paraTexts);");

            view.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('ParaText Disply' + paraTexts.toString());");
            Log.d("Output Test:"," onPageFinished");

        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(address);

    testOutput();

}

public void testOutput(){
    Log.d("Output Test:"," Print");
}

}
```

Comment: Please, if you're gonna vote down please clarify why I'm getting it. Don't just vote down and leave.

Comment: Of course. All events come after onCreate finished. What else? Rethink your design. But unclear which problem you face.